# dxa:media tag not recovering image

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.6

When using the `dxa:media` tag with a factor, then the url is changed, but the new image is not shown, neither published to disk.

Are we missing any interceptor in our project? How is working the media tag when resizing images?

Comment: How does the problematic URL look?

Comment: URL with resize -> /multimedia/images/nh-leonardo-da-vinci-bar-1_tcm47-60562_w160_n.jpg 
URL original -> /multimedia/images/nh-leonardo-da-vinci-bar-1_tcm47-60562.jpg